# Laravel authentication: localhost redirected you too many times laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Sorry if this question have already existsed. I'm building web application with Laravel framework and version is 5.3. I have a problem that you can help me. It's redirected you too many times when authentication.

**My route** :

```
Route::get('/', [
'as' => 'ui.home',
'uses' => 'HandleController@home'
]);
Auth::routes();
```

**My middleware** :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I see a problem cause from `Auth::check()`. But, I can't fixed it. Please help me.

Thank you,

Comment: Chmod 777 storage and chmod 775 vendor.

Comment: @mydo47 thanks. but I'm working on localhost

Comment: I don't understand. What's different localhost and server?

Answer (score 0):

may be the permission issue to the storage folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

ps: if you are in linux